# Find when $\frac{x^5-1}{x-1}$ is a perfect square?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math, diophantine-equations

$\textbf{Question:}$Find when $f(x)=\frac{x^5-1}{x-1}$ is a perfect square? where $x \in \mathbb N/ \{1\}$.

I tried upto certain number and somewhat convinced that $3$ is the only solution.But I failed to prove that.Here's what  I got so far:

If some prime $p \mid f(x)$  then, $p \equiv 1 \pmod{5}$ or $p=5$ .But I could deduce nothing useful from here so far.Then I tried factoring

$f(x)=(x^2+x+1)^2-x(x+1)^2$ like this.But still failed to make any useful conclusion.

I would appreciate both hints or full solutions.

Comment: $\ x=3\ $ is the only solution upto $\ x=10^9\ $

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint. We have that $f(2)=31$ and $f(3)=121=11^2$. For any integer $n>3$, show that
$$\left(n^2 + \left\lfloor\frac {n}{2}\right\rfloor\right)^2 < f(n)=\frac {n^5 - 1}{n - 1} < \left(n^2 + \left\lfloor\frac {n}{2}\right\rfloor+1\right)^2.$$